# To "new" or not to "new"

Tags: c#, .net, new-operator, allocation

Is there a rule of thumb to follow when to use the `new` keyword and when not to when declaring objects?

```
List<MyCustomClass> listCustClass = GetList();
```

OR

```
List<MyCustomClass> listCustClass = new List<MyCustomClass>();
listCustClass = GetList();
```

Comment: Are you really asking if you should write factories or not?

Comment: No, I think he doesn't understand that "new" means a constructor call and the creation of a new object. Otherwise he would know better than to create a new object and then throw it away. Maybe he's coming from VB.NET, where the "New" keyword can be part of the declaration syntax, so he thinks that's what it is in C#.

Comment: I'm not sure about the C# and .NET tags on this one since it's a pretty general OOP question.

Comment: I'd keep the tags, since I think this is not an OOP question; it's a "I don't understand the syntax of C#" question. He can't possibly be asking "when should I create an object and then throw it away in the next statement" (I hope).

Comment: I can accept that, which is why I left the tags on, but I'm thinking about how to make the question more generic for anyone who might type something like this into Google and wind up here. This can technically apply to Java and C++ and any other C-like language.

Comment: Great title, I think it should end in "that is the question", hahaha

Comment: Frankly, it's barely a question at all if John S is right.

Comment: I think we should find out from Bob Smith if I'm right about his misunderstanding. If I'm right, then this should be closed as "not a real question". It won't keep it from showing up in Google, but it will help, especially if Bob Smith edits his question to say what he was thinking of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your scenario it seems that the actual creation of the object is being performed inside your `GetList()` method.  So your first sample would be the correct usage.

When created, your `List<MyCustomClass>` is stored in the heap, and your `listCustClass` is simply a reference to that new object.  When you set listCustClass to `GetList()` the reference pointer of `listCustClass` is discarded and replaced with a reference pointer to whatever `GetList()` returns (could be null).  When this happens your original `List<MyCustomClass>` is still in the heap, but no objects point to it, so its just wasting resources until the Garbage Collector comes around and cleans it up.

To sum it up everytime you create a new object then abandon it, like the second example, you're essentially wasting memory by filling the heap with useless information.

Answer (score 43):

In your second case you are creating a new object on the first line just to throw it away on the second line. Completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 18):

Only your first example makes any sense in this case since in the second case you are immediately replacing the created list with the one returned by the method.  Initializing a list to a new empty list makes sense in the cases where you are adding to that list or when it is possible that the method you are calling to populate the list may somehow result in a null value when you would otherwise expect an empty list.

Examples where I might use initialization to a new, empty list.

```
List<MyCustomClass> listCustClass = new List<MyCustomClass>();
listCustClass.AddRange( GetList() );
```

or

```
List<MyCustomClass> listCustClass = new List<MyCustomClass>();
try
{
    listCustClass = GetList();
}
catch (SqlException)
{
}
return listCustClass;
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the `new` keyword to construct a new instance of an object. It is not clear from your question what the `GetList` method does, but presumably it is either creating a new list (thereby moving the `new` keyword somewhere else) or returning an existing list (which *someone* created at one point using `new`).

Comment: The GetList should be using new to create a list so that it can return it to the caller. right? Is there any other way of implementing the GetList?

Comment: The point is that someone is creating the list, whether it's GetList or some method that GetList calls.

Answer (score 3):

The new keyword is basically used to allocate space on the heap. If you are creating a value type (structs, etc...) you don't have to use the new keyword. However, reference variables have to be new'd before they are used.

In your above example, it seems as though GetList() is returning a reference that is of type List which would have been created (new'd) somewhere within the function. Hence in this scenario, new'ing is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

If you can inline it without losing meaning and clarity of what you're accomplishing, by all means, inline.

Edit: And, as I regularly inline, I didn't even think about the orphaned object reference. Doh. =)

Comment: Ahaha. My colleague kept missing with his mouse all day, too. Must be monday. =)

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule of thumb, but there is common sense that you can apply most of the time.

An object needs to be instantiated when it is being created. Your `GetList()` function ostensibly returns a (created) IList therefore the second code snippet is quite unnecessary (You instantiate an IList and effectively discard it on the next line).

The first snippet is entirely appropriate, however.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it in terms of "should I use new when I declare".

You use new when you are assigning (which can be part of a declaration).

The first example is correct, the second is a needless waste of runtime resources.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, all instances of classes have to be created with the `new` keyword. If you are not using `new` in your current context, you either have a null reference, or you are calling a function that uses `new` to instanciate the class.

In this case, it appears that GetList() uses `new` to create a new list.