# Creating new object then reallocating

Tags: c#, new-operator

A question which builds upon [To "new" or not to "new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768922/to-new-or-not-to-new)

```
Foo object1 = new Foo();
// some operations later ...
object1 = new Foo();
```

Is what I'm attempting to do advisable? and if `Foo` implements Idispoable, do I need to call dispose before calling the new operator the second time?

Comment: I hope you noticed in the referenced question that the OP simply didn't understand the C# syntax? Don't do what he did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you're doing in the example is fine.

The `object1` *variable* is simply a reference to an object of type `Foo`. After the first `new` assignment it refers to one particular instance of `Foo`; after the second `new` assignment it refers to a completely different instance (and the original instance becomes eligible for garbage collection, assuming that there's nothing else referencing it).

And yes, if `Foo` implements `IDisposable` then you should dispose it, preferably by using a `using` block, although my personal preference is to use separate `using` variables for each block:

```
using (Foo first = new Foo())
{
    // do something
}

using (Foo second = new Foo())
{
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, if a class implements `IDisposable`, then it is advisable to ensure that `Dispose()` gets called. That is almost always the right thing to do.

Comment: I would word that more strongly: "if a class implements IDisposable, you SHOULD call Dispose()" Preferably, wrap in a using statement wherever possible

Comment: @Mitch: WCF proxy class instances. Need I say more?

Comment: as I said "wherever possible "

Comment: @Mitch: so the wording would be "if a class implements IDisposable, you SHOULD call Dispose() WHENEVER POSSIBLE"?